# RadToolbar doesn't show Images

Tags: image, silverlight, telerik

I have an `RadToolbar` control on my Page. The problem is the Images I have placed on my buttons don't show. My code seems fine. Whats the issue?

```
 <telerik:RadToolBar Grid.Row="1"
                     Margin="20,20,5,10">
    <Button Width="25"
            Click="OnInsertClick">
        <Image Source="Images/add.png"/>
    </Button>
    <Button Width="25">
        <Image Source="Images/delete.png"/>
    </Button>
</telerik:RadToolBar>
```

I also tried addressing like `/Images/add.png` but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where your page is located in the project. If it's on the same level as Images folder, your code should work. But if it's in separate folder, you'll need to use dots to go up a level:

```
<Image Source="../Images/add.png"/>
```

If your page is located deeper in folder structure, you'll need to add dots for every level.

Alternatively, you can use full notation to avoid playing with dots (change the name for your assembly name from project properties):

```
<Image Source="/AssemblyName;component/Images/add.png"/>
```